# Extract thumb from you tube embedded URL in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, youtube, thumbnails

I have written a function in C# which is extracting thumb of you tube embedded URL but only for URL like  "https://youtu.be/8YDKDfkTbZU" i am not able to extract the actual thumb.How can i extract image from that kind of URL. Its working fine for URL like "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F2lN25IayH8".

Here is my current code

---

```
if( ShareHolocPostDesc.Contains( "youtube.com" ) )
                        {
                            int endPoint = ShareHolocPostDesc.IndexOf( "<iframe" );

                            ShareHolocPostDesc = ShareHolocPostDesc.Substring( 0, endPoint - 1 );
                            ShareHolocPostDesc = ShareHolocPostDesc.Replace( "<br/><br", "" );
                            string[] arrShareHolicDesc = ShareHolocPostDesc.Replace( "<br/><br", "" ).Split( "?v=".ToCharArray() );
                            string YouTubeVideoID = arrShareHolicDesc[arrShareHolicDesc.Length - 1];
                            YouTubeVideoID = YouTubeVideoID.Replace( "<br/>", "" );
                            YouTubeVideoID = YouTubeVideoID.Replace( "<br/", "" );
                            ogImage = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + YouTubeVideoID.Trim() + "/0.jpg";
                            }
```

---

```
  ShareHolocPostDesc="https://youtu.be/8YDKDfkTbZU <br/><iframe width='100%' height='450' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/8YDKDfkTbZU'></iframe>"
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i had to modify a little. https://youtu.be/ was extra in my image URL .

```
YouTubeVideoID = YouTubeVideoID.Replace( "<br/", "" ).Replace( "https://youtu.be/","" );
```

now it works .